# Import python file without setting variables again

Tags: python

Everytime the loop runs it should get the current_module variable from importfile.py. And if I type `use something`
it should change the current_module variable to "something" and print `console something >`  in the input

But when I run the function again in main.py the variable resets to the default `"default"` and just prints `console default >`

How would I make it not reset the variable and print the current module with the new value

main.py

```py
import importfile
while 1:
    current_module = importfile.main().current_module
    _input = input(f"console {current_module} > ") # always prints "default"
    importfile.main().checkinput(_input)
```

importfile.py

```py
class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_module="default"

    def checkinput(self,_input):
        _split = _input.split(" ", 1)
        if _split[0] == "use":
            self.current_module = _split[1]
```

Comment: Every time you call `main()` you're creating a new instance of the class that has a brand new `current_module` value.  Just do something like `main = importfile.main()` before your loop, and then use that same `main` object for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a class called `main`, then `main()` creates a new object of type `main`, by calling `main`'s `__init__` function.

Since you do this everytime round the `while` loop, each time you are creating new objects, with separate attributes, and calling their `__init__`s, and therefore setting the value of `self.current_module` to `"default"`.

In other words, `main() != main()`.

You could instead keep only one `main` object, and update that object every time round the `while` loop. e.g.

```
import importfile

m = importfile.main()

while 1:
    current_module = m.current_module
    _input = input(f"console {current_module} > ")
    m.checkinput(_input)
```